How to optimize the performance of a Webpack-bundled multi-tenant React Chatbot hosted in Azure
I’ve built a React chatbot application and bundled the code using Webpack. I’ve hosted the bundle.js file via Azure API Management (APIM) and I'm embedding the script into an HTML page that points to this bundled code.
Here's what happens:
Loading Process: When the HTML page loads, it pulls the bundle.js, which renders the chatbot UI.
API Calls: The chatbot makes API calls to load tenant-specific CSS and tokens.
WebSocket Connection: The bot then connects to a WebSocket backend using wss for chat functionality.
However, the loading and execution of bundle.js are extremely slow. It can take up to 30 seconds or more to fully render the chat UI and connect to the backend, even though APIM applies compression to the JS file.
Here are additional details about the setup:
The codebase is multi-tenant, so the bundle.js remains the same, but it uses a JSON object fetched via an API to render tenant-specific components (like UI, tokens, and styles).
The Chat Widget is embedded into the tenant's web app via script tags.
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.
What I’ve Tried:
APIM Compression: APIM already applies compression to the JavaScript file, but it hasn’t significantly improved load times.
Caching: Ensured that caching policies are enabled on APIM.
Questions:

Is there a better approach to handle this setup in terms of performance?
Would using a React widget (instead of a single large bundle.js) help with improving load times?
Could breaking the bundle.js file into smaller chunks and lazy-loading certain features improve performance?
Are there any optimizations or practices I can apply when using Azure APIM for serving the JavaScript bundle?


Please share the steps you have followed
